# Confirming attaching to Tangle

Tags: attach-to-tangle

How do i make sure a certain address is attached to Tangle and how do I attach it if it is not attached (as i see a new receiving address now)? For instance, I sent a few IOTAs (Mi) from one wallet to another with the following recipient address FUTOOUZXF9O9ISLDOR9VRUKOUASCBJGPJAIFVDXKE9IINTIFJCSVRXBRETLTOMKNNVZCOIZVWAWUNMFVZZRZXSOSEZ

While https://thetangle.org/ confirms receiving the transaction, it does not show in the wallet history as pending. This has not been the case earlier.

Comment: I still haven't received funds in my wallet. Not sure if something is terribly wrong with the IOTA network. Guys, need help here please.

Comment: Make sure you are connected to an up-to-date node (https://iota.dance/nodes), then you should see your transactions. If not, make sure that you use the same seed as you used when generating that address.

Comment: Almost sure there's no issue with the node. Is there a way to trace the SEED from the address at all? I know it's not possible. Just looking for probabilities here.

Comment: Are you saying you entered the wrong recipient address? Do you see the address in the HISTORY tab of the wallet?

Answer (score 0):

If I know it right, the wallet send an zero-transaction to the new address when you attach it to the tangle.

At least since the tx is confirmed, the wallet should show it too. Did you have the same issue with another fullnode?

Comment: No. I think the issue is I might have mistyped the Seed and now i can't remember. The whole IOTA seed entry design is to blame. One mistake and you're done and there's no way to retrieve this. I hope IOTA PAYS for this kinda faulty wallet design. NO OTHER WALLET OUT THERE HAS THIS PROBLEM.

Comment: And I guess there's no way to contact the IOTA team, explain the whole thing and get it rectified. There's just NO SUPPORT. All this becuase there's no second layer of security like 2FA or password encryption to make it failsafe. Super screw up from IOTA and I hope they grow up and take some responsibility instead of putting the blame ENTIRELY on the users and the thieves.

Comment: But you have both seeds? Then you can check if the Adress where you send the transaction to exists in the seed (you can also try to generate a few new addresses in that seed).
Did you manual typed the seed in the wallet?

Comment: Yes. That's the mistake I made. Major error.